# Is there a way to call BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() on a single object?

Tags: android, listview, adapter, listadapter, baseadapter

Is there a way to call [BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) on a single element in the adapter.

What I am trying to do is update the data and reflect those changes in the containing ListView.  The problem is that sometimes the change is so small that it seems ridiculous that I have to refresh the whole view rather than the single item in the view that has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of such method. If it's really important, you can always find individual item view to update. But I don't think that it worth it as Android is pretty efficient in updating list views. So it will not do much extra work (definitelly not going beyond items currently visible on the screen).